# Posts with wrong (meta) data

Tags: support

For the last weeks I sometimes see posts with wrong data at SF.

recent:
[How to connect to a linux machine that changes IP regularly?](https://serverfault.com/questions/939722/how-to-connect-to-a-linux-machine-that-changes-ip-regularly)

[image]

Is that known?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The duration "7 days ago" appears to be accurate.

Keep in mind that times displayed on SF are in UTC.

In particular, the question was posted on 2018-11-12 21:41:30Z. The current time is 2018-11-20 17:09:15Z. When the time reaches 21:41:30Z in a little over four hours then the duration displayed will change to "8 days ago".

If you hover the mouse over the duration, then it will also display the timestamp.

[image: Timestamp screenshot]